# My Spring DispatcherServlet is not found when i tried to insert css in my jsp. Why?

Tags: css, spring, jsp, mapping, dispatcher

I have tried during many days, I have seen many posts, and I can't resolve this problem.
When I want to put a css into my jsp and load my page I have this :

2019-11-15 11:00:38.895  WARN 11504 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/genius/css/carousel.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

My Arborescense:

```
src-----
        |main
         --------
                 |java
         --------
                 |resources
                 ---------application-properties.txt
         --------
                 |webapp
                 ---------|resources
                           ---------
                                    | genius    
                                    ---------|css
                                                ---------bootstrap.min.css 
                                                ---------carousel.css 
                                                ---------font-awesome.min.css 
                                    ---------|font
                                    ---------|js
                                    ---------|images

                                    ---------style.css                         
                 ---------|WEB-INF
```

My jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/genius/css/carousel.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/genius/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/genius/css/font-awesome.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>My title</title>
</head>

<body class ="left-menu">
<div class="menu-wrapper">
    <header class="vertical-header">
        <div class="vertical-header-wrapper">
            <nav class="nav-menu">
                <div class="logo">

                </div>

            </nav>

        </div>

    </header>

</div>
<div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to with

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

    <spring:url value="/resources/genius/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bootstrapCss" />
    <link href="${bootstrapCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/genius/css/font-awesome.min.css" var="fontAwesomeCss" />
    <link href="${fontAwesomeCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/genius/css/carousel.css" var="carousel" />
    <link href="${carousel}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/genius/style.css" var="styleCss" />
    <link href="${styleCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But the tag spring isn't found...

My Dispatcher :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/genius/" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.app.controller" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" /> <!--  /WEB-INF/jsp/ -->
        <beans:property name="suffix" value="*.jsp" /><!-- .jsp -->
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

/WEB-INF/jsp don't work. To display my jsp I had to go through application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.com=TRACE
```

So I wonder if there is not something similar to do for the css.

In a other of tried I test with :

```
 <annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/classpath:/resources/genius/" />
```

My Arborescense for this test:

```
src-----
        |main
         --------
                 |java
         --------
                 |resources
                 ---------|resources
                           ---------
                                    | genius    

                                      ---------|css
                                                ---------bootstrap.min.css 
                                                ---------carousel.css 
                                                ---------font-awesome.min.css 
                                      ---------|font
                                      ---------|js
                                      ---------|images

                                      ---------style.css 
                 ---------application-properties.txt
         --------
                 |webapp

                 ---------|WEB-INF
```

The last thing I have tried is to add  in my dispatcher ...

Thank you for explaining to me what I forget.

Comment: Are static resources located under ../genius/genius/..   ?

Comment: In the folder /genius/css there are the three files that I want to use (  I mistakenly put 2 times genius in my post, I edit. )

Comment: Nobody can help ? :/